# Insert table into docx File using DocX project

Tags: c#

I create a word document using DocX project.

I need to insert table into my doc , but I don't know what should I do?

```
string fileName = @"D:\Users\John\Documents\DocXExample.docx";

// Create a document in memory:
var doc = DocX.Create(fileName);

// Insert a paragrpah:
//doc.InsertParagraph("This is my first paragraph");

// Save to the output directory:
doc.Save();

// Open in Word:
Process.Start("WINWORD.EXE", fileName);
```

Comment: Are you after [this?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2dw39e8e.aspx)

Comment: Thats good then. Now you know what to do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample code :

```
Table t = document.AddTable(20,2);
t.Rows[0].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append("value1");
t.Rows[1].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append("value2");
t.Rows[2].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append("value3");
```